# Extract string from Python re

Tags: python

How do you extract the original 'raw' string from a Python regex.  For example, I have
the following simple regex:

```
import re
test_line_re = re.compile(r'Test \d+ Result: \s+')
```

I want to be able to print: `Test \d+ Result \s+`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `pattern` attribute:

```
print test_line_re.pattern
```

You should always search through [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.pattern) when you have questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> re.compile(r'Test \d+ Result: \s+').pattern
'Test \\d+ Result: \\s+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't store the string before compiling the expression? i.e.

```
import re
pattern = r'Test \d+ Result: \s+'
test_line_re = re.compile(pattern)
print pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

`re.compile` is not very useful. It usually best just to keep the pattern the whole time anyhow. You can get the pattern from the `pattern` attribute, but if possible just don't ever manually compile it.